# Using File Transfer Plugin in Phonegap Application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I have more than 2 weeks that i tried to download file PDF in phonegap application using the File Transfer Plugin but it didn't work!! i make everything for that:
-installing the last version of phonegap
-installing the last version of File Transfer plugin
And this is the code to integrate in Javascript interface:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
    "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png",
    "file://sdcard/ics-android.png",
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    });
```

But it seems wrong!!! I have like a result last three alerts in an android device:
-Download error source 
-Download error target
-Upload error code
What i should doing?!!

Comment: Can you write what error codes do you get?

Comment: when i access to the application , it displays: "download error source [http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png] " and after that it displays "download error target  file://sdcard/ics-android.png" and finally "upload error code".. I tested many URLs but the problem persists..

Answer (score 1):

Request you to check out my [github page](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations) that contains a sample Cordova app which downloads PDF file from external URL and downloads it to the device.

This sample app is tested both in iOS and android devices. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your solution is very interesting too and i tested it..and finaaaally it works: it displays the file without downloading and it's sufficient..You saved my life    as an engineer..thank you veeeery much!

Comment: @Hamza Belheni actually it downloads  the file locally and then displays it. Check out the code completely. Also glad that it helped you

Comment: @Ghandi i have one other small problem and i need your help please:How can i call these functions(defined in the body of the application) in my webview (a website that i developed).To make the problem easier,How can I call any Javascript function defined in the body of the application in my webview?it's urgent

Comment: @HamzaBelheni Sorry, i m not able to undesrtand your question

Comment: @Ghandi I m sorry if i didn't explain my question.I developed an application that contains one line of code that oriented you directly when you install and open it to my website(concept of webview). When navigating in my website using this application, i want to use the plugin that opened the PDF File which is defined the body of the application..When i call the download function,it does not recognize it.

Comment: @HamzaBelheni If i undestand your question right, you are trying to invoke file download plugin from your website. If this is the case, then you gotta use inappbrowser plugin to open your website and attach some event to invoke you plugin. Check out this link -http://www.telerik.com/blogs/details/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser

Comment: @Ghandi Exactly this is my problem and what you submit to me is very interesting.I tested a big number of application's versions but when i tried for example to call a function which displays alert when clicking a button in my webview, it didn't call this function defined in the body of the application.I tested executeScript and many examples but nothing is clear..Did you have an example please?

Comment: @HamzaBelheni sorry to say that I don't have any working sample as I moved sometime back from mobile app development to main stream product development. But what I could say is generally Cordova apps are meant to be SPA. So that all functions defined is available across the app. In your case I don't exactly understand your webview implementation. Bare minimum code I have is registering events in InAppBrowser which opens external URL. Link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_InAppBrowser/blob/master/www/js/app.js

Answer (score 0):

According to [file transfer plugin documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/#sample), first of all you need to create a file where you will store your remote data. Your code should look like this:

```
{
    //call this after onDeviceReady event
    ...
    var savePath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
    var fileName = "ics-android.png";
    var url = encodeURI("http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png");

    downloadFile(savePath, fileName, url);
    ...
}



function downloadFile(savePath, fileName, remoteURL) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(savePath, function (dirEntry) {
        console.log('file system open: ' + dirEntry.name);
        createFile(dirEntry, fileName, function (fileEntry) {
            download(remoteURL, fileEntry);
        });
    }, function (err) { alert(err) });
}

function createFile(dirEntry, fileName, callback) {
    // Creates a new file or returns the file if it already exists.
    dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        callback(fileEntry);
    }, function (err) { alert(err) });

}
function download(remoteURL, fileEntry) {
    var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(
        remoteURL,
        fileURL,
        function (entry) {
            alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("download error source " + error.source);
            alert("download error target " + error.target);
            alert("upload error code" + error.code);
        });
}
```

Note that for path I use cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, so you get root sdcard path for file.

Comment: I tested your code but it didn't call download(remoteURL, fileEntry)!! i have installed the plugin cordova-plugin-file which is used for the FS but it still not working!! Can you test your solution please to be sure that the problem isn't from a bad configuration or installation of file or something like that...Thank you very much

Comment: @HamzaBelheni I fixed my solution. Try now

Comment: I think that we are very near of our solution but it didn't display and download the file! when i try to know the value of savePath, it displays in the alert (undefined) ! but i excute from the first time your code, it displays the alert (download complete:) but without downloading any file..after that this alert didn't displaying in my application!